# Any way to save the state of a imageView that show an image retrieved from url?

Tags: java, android

In my application I show a picture retrieved from url, but it is lost after the device is rotated, I save the state of the textview inmy application, using bundle, there is a way to save and recover the image?

Answer (score 1):

Store the picture on a file, save the filename of the file on a bundle and then when restored from a bundle get the filename, then get the picture from the file and put it on your imageView.

BTW, Have you looked at http://square.github.io/picasso/, or https://github.com/koush/ion